# Are C++11 objects potentially slower in multi-threaded environments because of the new const?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, constants

According to Herb Sutter (http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/you-dont-know-const-and-mutable-herb-sutter), in C++11 const methods must not alter the object bit-wise, or must perform internal synchronization (e.g. using a mutex) if they have mutable data members.

Suppose I have a global object that I'm accessing from multiple threads and suppose it has mutable members. For the sake of argument, let's assume that we cannot modify the source of the class (it's provided by a third-party).

In C++98 these threads would use a global mutex to synchronize access to this object. So, an access would require a single mutex lock/unlock.

However, in C++11, any const member function call on this object will invoke internal synchronization as well, so potentially, a single const function call on this object will cost 2 lock/unlock operations (or more, depending on how many functions you call from a single thread). Note that the global mutex is still needed, because const doesn't seem to do anything for writers (except possibly slowing them down as well, if one of the non-const methods calls a const method).

So, my question is: If all of our classes have to be this way in C++ (at least to be usable by STL), doesn't this lead to excessive synchronization measures?

Thanks

**Edit:** Some clarifications:

1. It seems that in C++11, you cannot use a class with the standard library unless its const member functions are internally synchronized (or do not perform any writes).
2. While C++11 doesn't automatically add any synchronization code itself, a standard-library-compliant class doesn't need synchronization in C++98, but needs it in C++11. So, in C++98 you can get away with not doing any internal synchronization for mutable members, but in C++11 you can't.

Comment: C++11 doesn't add any hidden magic code. The article you cite describes new *design* idioms. So your class *shouldn't* have const access if that isn't thread-safe, etc. Nobody will add any random locks for you.

Comment: @Kerrek: No, they won't. However, C++11-compliant and C++98-compliant classes have different requirements, I clarified them in my edits. This is about comparing a C++98-compliant class with a C++11-compliant one, it's not about the same codebase.

Comment: Your clarifications are simply not true, a class without synchronisation is not "non-compliant" in any way

Comment: @Jonathan: Please check the video at 11:35, 13:18, 14:00.
Admittedly, he doesn't say it's required from *all* const functions, but it is required from some operators for sure.

Comment: If I create a `std::pair<MyType1, MyType2>` and I never share that between threads **there is no need for those types to be thread-safe**, see 10:09 where it talks about objects **accessible by threads other than the current thread**. If you have a global accessed by multiple threads, then yes, you need to make it thread-safe, but you can continue using the global mutex you already used in C++98, nothing changes. If the third-party vendor of that type adds expensive internal synchronisation and that causes a problem for you then complain to the vendor, don't blame the standard.

Comment: @Alex: You seem to be missing a huge point: 99.999% of all const member functions do not perform any writes. For the 0.001% that do, they need to ensure no races occur. This is so far from the main case it's almost irrelevant. Your #2 simply isn't true. #2 only applies to those 0.001% of classes. So for 99.999% of classes in C++11, you can absolutely do without internal synchronization.

Comment: Also, "the new const" is not new, it's just a formalisation of the ["Client must lock shared mutable containers"](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html) rules that pre-date the 1998 standard. The "new" part is formally equating "read accesses" with `const` member functions and "write accesses" with non-`const` member functions, but that shouldn't be a big conceptual leap for anyone who's been writing sane multi-threaded code prior to the C++11 standard.

Comment: I watched Herb back as it was fresh, and tried to find actual differences regarding const. And didn't really find them. I understand the issue is more like clarification and declaration of what we had, and a more expressed guideline for design. Not a change in rules, semantics or whatever really.

Comment: @GManNickG: I clarified #2 with "for mutable members", I assumed it was obvious from the very first sentence.
As for not being true, well, the fact that there's 0.001% that it applies to makes it true.

Comment: The only reason you could "get away with not doing any internal synchronization" in C++98 was because the standard didn't say anything about threads, but if you were actually using multiple threads then you always had to use some form of synchronisation, internal or external, and that hasn't changed.  Nothing **requires** classes to do internal synchronisation, it's OK to ensure they are never shared between threads, or if they are shared it's OK to use external synchronisation to make it safe.  That hasn't changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. You should make your objects follow these guidelines, and therefore access to them will potentially be slower in C++11. If ***and only if***:

1. The class has `mutable` members which `const` member functions modify.
2. The object is being accessed from multiple threads.

If you ensure that at least one of these is untrue, then nothing changes. The number of objects that are being accessed from multiple threads should always be as minimal as possible. And the number of classes that have mutable members should be minimal. So you're talking about a minimal set of a minimal set of objects.

And even then... all that is required is that data races will not be broken. Depending on what the mutable data even is, this could simply be an atomic access.

I fail to see the problem here. Few of the standard library objects will have mutable members. I defy you to find a reasonable implementation of `basic_string`, `vector`, `map`, etc that need mutable members.

> It seems that in C++11, you cannot use a class with the standard library unless its const member functions are internally synchronized (or do not perform any writes).

This is incorrect. You most certainly can. What you *cannot* do is attempt to access that class across multiple threads in a way that would "perform any writes" on those mutable members. If you never access that object through that C++11 class across threads in that particular way, you're fine.

So yes, you can use them. But you only get the guarantees that your own class provides. If you use your class *through* a standard library class in an unreasonable way (like your `const` member functions not being *`const`* or properly synchronized), then that's *your fault*, not the library's.

> So, in C++98 you can get away with not doing any internal synchronization for mutable members, but in C++11 you can't.

That's like saying you can get away with computer crime back in the Roman Empire. Of course you can. They didn't have *computers* back then; so they didn't know what computer crime *was*.

C++98/03 did not have the concept of "threading". Thus, the standard has no concept of "internal synchronization", so what you could or could not "get away with" was neither defined nor undefined. It made no more sense to ask that question of the standard than to ask what the hacking laws were during Ceaser's day.

Now that C++11 actually defines this concept and the idea of a race condition, C++11 is able to say when you can "get away with not doing any internal synchronization".

Or, to put it another way, here is how the two standards answer your question: What is the result of a potential data race on a `mutable` member when accessed via a member function declared `const` in the standard library?

C++11: There will be no data races on any internal members when accessed by a `const` function. All standard library implementations of such functions must be implemented in such a way that a data race cannot occur.

C++98/03: What's a data race?

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, and pulls the various points I made across several comments into one coherent answer, with a good analogy - nicely done.

Answer (score 10):

> in C++11, any const member function call on this object will invoke internal synchronization as well

Why?  That synchronisation doesn't just magically appear in the class, it's only there if someone adds it explicitly.

> so potentially, a single const function call on this object will cost 2 lock/unlock operations

Only if someone has added an internal mutex to it **and** you also use an external one ... but why on earth would you do that?

> Note that the global mutex is still needed, because const doesn't seem to do anything for writers (except possibly slowing them down as well, if one of the non-const methods calls a const method).

If the class has an internal mutex that's used to make the `const` members thread-safe then it could also be used for non-`const` members.  If the class doesn't have an internal mutex, then the situation is identical to the C++98 one.

I think you're seeing a problem that doesn't exist.

Herb's "new meaning for const" is not enforced by the language or compiler, it's just design guidance, i.e. an idiom for good code.  To follow that guidance you don't add mutexes to every class so `const` members are allowed to modify `mutable` members, **you avoid mutable members!**  In the rare cases where you absolutely must have mutable members, either require users to do their own locking (and clearly document the class as requiring external synchronisation) or add internal synchronisation and pay the extra cost ... but those situations should be rare, so it's not true that "C++11 objects are slower because of the new const" because most well-designed objects don't have mutable members anyway.

Comment: "either require users to do their own locking" - well that's the thing. It's not just for a good code, it's REQUIRED if you want to use these classes with the standard library.
So, this means that basically *all* C++ classes need to be modified to support this.

Comment: @Alex: If your classes have lots of mutable members, then you deserve broken code. And if your classes don't have mutable members, then your code won't need modification. So I don't see the problem here.

Comment: _"it's REQUIRED if you want to use these classes with the standard library"_ -- why?  Only if you want to use them in ways that involve concurrent, unsynchronised access from multiple threads.  I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @Nicol: Sorry, but this is not about *lots* of mutable members. One class with one mutable member is all it takes.
As for their usefulness, they can be used, for example for internal caching, and this is a perfectly valid code.

Comment: @Jonathan: Because it says so in the C++11 standard (or at least that's how I understood it from Herb's talk).

Comment: It **doesn't** say so.  The standard promises classes in the standard library meet those requirements (but **very** few classes in the standard library have mutable members or non-const static members or other "non-local" data shared between independent objects) but it doesn't require anything of user-defined types.  If this causes a problem for you then you're doing it wrong: either you have too many `mutable` members or you're sharing too many objects between threads. Stop doing that and life is easier.